# how to test form submission in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm sending some param via form post from my template and the action in my controller is handling it accordingly.

Now I want to write a test case for that action. How should I make that dummy request so that Request.Form["selectedSuppliersHidden"] will work in controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to use Request.Form in MVC

Give this a read: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx

If you handle posting correctly then you'll have an Action that can accept variables and be tested a lot easier.

**EDIT**
You can use the FormCollection param in your Action, something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string btnSubmit, FormCollection collection)
{
    //btnSubmit this is the button that is clicked.
    return View();
}
```

The FormCollection will have everything in it from the Request.Form collection. But you should still be able to post the right hand listbox in the normal MVC way

Comment: I had a special case for what I had to make that Request.Form ... but now I need to test it also

Comment: You'll need to highlight what that special case is and maybe include some code. Also you'd need to fake the Request object in your test methods, not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: I want a dropdown like this [link](http://www.voidcanvas.com/demo/7511pair-select/) .... And I have to post everything in the right hand side dropdown

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves my Request.Form problem. But Here is another one.... Now from my test method, even if I send null value to some parameters of my model (those parameters had [Required] attribute), it says ModelState.IsValid = true

Comment: But it should have been false

Comment: If this solves your problem, can you accept my answer. Your other problem sounds like a separate issue and in which case you'll need to start a new question and also provide some code, cannot give a proper solution without it. Thanks

Comment: Actually the thing was controller doesn't deal with model validation. Hence the problem I mentioned is not a part controller unit test. So my all problems are solved :)